# Namespace error while defining a BitVector32 collection in C#

Tags: c#, collections, namespaces, visual-studio-2019, bitvector

I have written the following code in visual studio 2019, but it gives me an error saying that **BitVector32 is a namespace but is used as a type here** and **CreateMask() method is not existing in the BitVector32 namespace**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Specialized;

namespace BitVector32
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            basicVector();
        }

        public static void basicVector()
        {

            BitVector32 b = new BitVector32(0);

            int myBit1 = BitVector32.CreateMask();
            int myBit2 = BitVector32.CreateMask(myBit1);
            int myBit3 = BitVector32.CreateMask(myBit2);
            int myBit4 = BitVector32.CreateMask(myBit3);
            int myBit5 = BitVector32.CreateMask(myBit4);

        }

    }
}
```

i referred the Microsoft doc at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.specialized.bitvector32?view=netcore-3.1 and did the same but it gives the above mentioned errors

Comment: You see line 4 of your program there, where you've reused the name `BitVector32` as a namespace. That's what the compiler's finding before the collection of the same name in `System.Collections.Specialized` - try being a bit more creative in naming your projects/namespaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to your namespace at the top being `BitVector32`. Change the namespace to another name other than `BitVector32`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Specialized;

namespace SomethingOtherThanBitVector32
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            basicVeector();
        }

        public static void basicVeector()
        {

            BitVector32 b = new BitVector32(0);

            int myBit1 = BitVector32.CreateMask();
            int myBit2 = BitVector32.CreateMask(myBit1);
            int myBit3 = BitVector32.CreateMask(myBit2);
            int myBit4 = BitVector32.CreateMask(myBit3);
            int myBit5 = BitVector32.CreateMask(myBit4);

        }

    }
}
```